# 4in6 tunnel for heterogeneous systems

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, tunneling, ipv4

I have clients (OS X 10.9 and Linaro/Ubuntu) in a native IPv6 network and a Server (Debian) in both native IPv4 and IPv6.
The Plan is to use the Server as a gateway of sorts, as in 4in6 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4in6) or 4over6.

An optimal solution would be a high performance (100MBit) connection with support for port forwarding and DynDNS, all for IPv4. The minimal requirement is the ability to connect to an OpenVPN Server which operates on IPv4 and which I cannot configure myself, running in the external IPv4 network:

```
(Clients) -- [[[OpenVPN]IPv4]IPv6] -- (Server) -- [[OpenVPN]IPv4] -- (OpenVPN Server)
```

- (Host)
- [Protocol encapsulation]
- -- connection --

Hardware details: Clients:

- slow 1GHZ ARM (Linaro), the performance bottleneck
- fast MacBook (OS X 10.9)
- Server: Core 2 Quad, 2.4GHz, 8 GB RAM, 100MBit/s (Debian)

I know that there are software solutions which can tunnel IPv4 in IPv6:
*Gif, GRE, AFTR, OpenVPN.*

I don't know if any of these fulfills the constraints:

- Good performance on slow ARM (Linaro, 1GHz Single Core Allwinner A10 CPU)
- Interoperable on OS X 10.9, Linaro (*Ubuntu for arm*) and Debian

**---April 16th---**
mac-gre is back in active development. To this day a beta version is available for OS X 10.9:
https://code.google.com/p/mac-gre/source/checkout
The developer warned me about a current error, so anybody trying this should take care about this:

> NOTE: there's a known issue that, when you unload the driver
>   (kextunload GRE.kext),  the system would probably KERNEL PANIC. So, do
>   NOT put the BETA version driver GRE.kext into
>   /System/Library/Extension/, just leave it in /tmp/ for testing.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Your question is not clear enough, could you reword it, and add some more details?

Comment: Hello! I reworded my question and added more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution: SSH port forwarding.

> ssh user@host -L 1194:localhost:1194

Then start OpenVPN on the client

In terms of performance, the ARM's maximum speed over Ethernet using OpenVPN is around 2-3MByte/s. With and without SSH, this is its best.